# Regular Expression validate HHMM string

Tags: regex

I have a regex to validate a string containing 'HHMM' or 'HHMM,HHMM'
This is what I am using:

```
^[0-2][0-9][0-5][0-9],[0-2][0-9][0-5][0-9]$
```

This sort of works in that `1247` is ok `3247` is not.
Similarly `1247,2200` is ok but `1247,2290` is not.

However, to allow for 24 hour clock values such as `2500` cannot be allowed.
Is there a way to put a check in regex that if first part of hour is `2` that second part can only be `0-4`?

Comment: **don't reinvent the wheel**..there are methods you can use to validate dates..which language are you using!

Comment: And please read the description of the tag your use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, use `|` to separate the `0x` and `1x` cases from `2y`:

```
^(?:[01][0-9]|2[0-4])[0-5][0-9],(?:[01][0-9]|2[0-4])[0-5][0-9]$
```

The `(?:...)` creates a non-capturing group, limiting the scope of the `|` operator. If you did want to capture the `HH` value (e.g. to use it in a replacement later or something), use `(...)` instead.

**Update:** Allowing `2400` but avoiding all other invalid times like `2411` can be done with another `|`:

```
(?:(?:[01][0-9]|2[0-3])[0-5][0-9]|2400)
```

However I would argue that it's better to just disallow any `24MM` (including `2400`) at all since it really should be written `00MM`. In this case the regex just becomes:

```
^(?:[01][0-9]|2[0-3])[0-5][0-9],(?:[01][0-9]|2[0-3])[0-5][0-9]$
```

Comment: Thanks that helps a good bit. But just discovered that values like 2411 are valid with this too so need to add check for that.
But I suppose 0000 - 2359 is good enough as I doubt anyone uses 2400 anyhow

Comment: @En-Motion, thanks, exactly. Updated the post for both cases. But 0000-2359 seems the best way to go.

Comment: @En-Motion - Don't forget to accept an answer. It will help you to get more answers to your questions in the future.

Answer (score 0):

you can use an OR expression in regex `(2[0-4]|[01][0-9])`

so it would look like `^(?:2[0-4]|[01][0-9])[0-5][0-9],(?:2[0-4]|[01][0-9])[0-5][0-9]$`

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional [regexps](http://www.regular-expressions.info/conditional.html), and a tutorial [here](http://www.asiteaboutnothing.net/regex/regex-conditionals.html).

Answer (score 0):

Yes,

```
^([0-1][0-9]|2[0-4])([0-5][0-9])(,([0-1][0-9]|2[0-4])([0-5][0-9]))?$
```

i hope it will work for you.